# How can i rename Time column when i using Time Range and Time Grain in superset

Tags: apache-superset

When I make a chart in superset, I was using Time column and Time Grain. And then I checked 'Include Time' Checkbox. At that time, I can see that 'Time' column added. but I want to change column name 'Time' to '날짜'(korean). Can I customize column name?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't really rename this as a metric. But you can use a hack to change the translation file.

Update the `superset/translations/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.json` and `messages.po` in your installation, and replace the 'Time column' string with your required string.

Side effect is that it will replace the string in all of the Superset.